# Eigenvalues of $A^*A$

Tags: linear-algebra

How can we show that eigenvalues for $A^*A$ are real and positive without using the Singular Value Decomposition theorem (where $A$ is a complex square matrix and $A^*$ its Hermitian conjugate)?

Comment: Do you know how to show that the eigenvalues of a self-adjoint matrix are real?

Comment: Hi, have you tried to prove it by proving $A^* A$ is positive-semidefinite? a hint would be $(A^* Ax, y) = (Ax, Ay)$, where $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is the standard inner product

Answer (score 10):

The eigenvalues of $A^*A$ can be zero, so what you want to show is that they are non-negative:
Take any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A^*A$, Let $v$ be an associated non-zero eigenvector. $0\leq\langle Av,Av\rangle=\langle A^*Av,v \rangle=\lambda ||v||^2$, which implies that $\lambda\geq 0$. In particular, $\lambda$  is real and non-negative.

Comment: Another way is to say that for every matrix $B$, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ if and only if $\bar{\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $B^*$, which implies (how?) that the eigenvalues of $B$, if $B$ is self-adjoint, are real ($B=B^*$). Since $A^*A$ is self-adjoint (check!) the result follows.

Comment: I was looking for the non-negative part and the above answer is a nice one.

Comment: @user10386: Then vote it up and accept... :)

Comment: Please do not give complete answers to homework problems.